# How to pass site URL of where the bot is hosted to the bot service and log it in app insights for every message?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to pass the site URL/referrer of where the bot is hosted on every message so I can track the bot across different sites that it'll be hosted on.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to send the site url to your backend along with each user message right?

Comment: @DipanshuKumarSuman - Correct! I think channelData can be used for this but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have posted an answer, see if it helps you. If yes, please mark it as accepted to help others.

Comment: Sorry, this not what I'm looking for. It should send the url to the bot on connecting along with the userid and name subsequently when sending messages.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet you are using to send messages from the client? You want to send the URL only on connection or on each message?

Answer (score 0):

You can send any extra data inside the `value` field of `activity` object.

Example:

```json
{
  "type":"message",
  "text":"Hi!",
  "value":{
     "siteUrl":"www.example.com"
  }
}
```

To clear your doubt on channelData, You cannot use it for your own implementation needs as per my knowlegde, it is specific to the channel which you are using with bot-framework. [See here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)